# How would I filter rainwater to substitute having to buy distilled water?

Tags: clothing, water, laundry

I have recently had a rainwater tank installed and it is connected to my laundry.

How would I filter rainwater to substitute having to buy distilled water for certain applications like placing water in my clothes iron?

Comment: One uses desilled water to avoid limestone to plug up the device.
In rainwater, you don't have to deal with limestone, however, you have to catch the rain in some way.
If you catch the rain on your roof, for example, you will find dirt in your water which could plug your device too.
So at least, you should filter the rainwater with a coffeefilter or so.

Comment: Hi! This question does not appear to be about a Lifehack as defined by the scope. The post ask for the benefit of something and does not seem to be about a problem mostly.

Comment: I use the water that the tumble drier extracts. That's distilled too.

Comment: I think this is a good question, so I looked up why it would be on hold. Well, I'd say this is a general "how to" question, and it's not a common problem.  We could tell you to boil it and catch the condensed water vapor, or filter it out purify it, but none of these solutions are very much hacky.

Comment: I thought that it might have fit under "Questions asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to achieve a certain task or solve a specific problem", that is, can rainwater be used as a replacement for distilled water?

Answer (score 1):

Distilled water is can be made.  These instructions use common items so that you can envision this easier, not because you need those specific items.

- Put a coffee cup in the center of a cooking pot.
- Pour rain water into the pot, being careful not to get any in the cup.
- Cover the pot with clear plastic wrap ( it doesn't have to be super tight )
- Seal the wrap to the pot with a rubber band, you don't want any of the air escaping.
- Place a small rock in the middle of the wrap.  It should weigh the wrap down, and the lowest point of the wrap should be directly above the cup.
- Place the pot on a radiator.
- Wait

The water is going to evaporate, leaving behind any debris in the pot.  The water vapor will condense on the plastic wrap.  As this distilled water collects, the slope of the wrap will cause it to flow to the center.  Drops of water will form and eventually weigh do much as to fall off the wrap and into your cup.

It will take a long time, a couple of ounces a day, maybe.  The idea is there, collect condensed water.  A pressure cooker would probably work great for heating water.  Attach a hose to the sream release and put a cup at the other end of the hose.  You just have to be sure about your rate of condensation.

There is laboratory equipment made specifically for doing this type of thing.

Answer (score -1):

Rainwater can hold dirt and other debris when it amkes contact with surfaces that are capturing the rain (roof etc)

You can always filter them using 2-3 coffee filters to filter out the debris, and then use that for your iron, and other applications that need to use 'distilled' water.